# Prevent insecure function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, security, supabase, supabase-database

I have an application that, upon registration, creates a friend code for the user. In order for the codes to be unique, in the table in the supabase I made a column with the `isUnique` parameter and additionally, I make a query to check if the database already has such a friend code.

I understand that this is not safe, because in the `network` tab you can track the request and pull out user data.

> When I talk about the network tab, I mean request url in it, which you can edit and paste in console

JS Code:

```
async function generateFriendCode() {
    let new_code = Math.floor(Math.random() * (1000000 - 0 + 1) + 0)
    const { data: codes, error: codes_error } = await supabase.from('profile').select('friend_code').eq('friend_code', new_code)
    if(codes.length == 0) {
        return new_code
    }
}
```

Given the fact that this function is called at the time of authorization, the user does not yet have a session, which means that the only condition of the RLS policy that I can make is whether he is authorized or not. In this situation, the user is NOT authorized, which means that supabase will return an empty array in the request.

I want my app to be more secure. How can I get the same result but be more secure and not be able to trace my users' data? Is the deal in special RLS Policy or in something else?

user profile definition from supabase:

```
create table
  public.profile (
    id uuid not null,
    name text null,
    bday text null,
    language text null,
    achiev_status_id bigint null default '1'::bigint,
    completed_routes numeric not null default '0'::numeric,
    completed_achievements numeric not null default '1'::numeric,
    profile_image_number text null,
    event_team text null,
    friend_code text not null,
    email text null,
    profile_image_number_last text null,
    constraint profile_pkey primary key (id),
    constraint profile_friend_code_key unique (friend_code),
    constraint profile_achiev_status_id_fkey foreign key (achiev_status_id) references achievements (id),
    constraint profile_id_fkey foreign key (id) references auth.users (id)
  ) tablespace pg_default;

create trigger update_profile_image_number_trigger
after
update of achiev_status_id on profile for each row
execute function update_profile_image_number ();
```

Comment: You can create a security definer function that takes a friend_code as an argument and returns a profile if there are any with the given friend_code.
https://supabase.com/docs/guides/database/functions

Comment: Gonna try it later, thanks!